# how can I specify a div to go under a div even it is outside the div

Tags: css

I want a div to go inside another div even if it is somewhere else.how can I do this ?

```
<div id="main">
</div>
<div id="sub">
</div>
```

How can I put the div "sub" inside the div "main" without actually writing the div "sub" inside "main".But I want to do this in a relative manner so that if the content of the sub increase the main also increases.Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Why don't you want to put the "sub" div inside the "main" div?  That is kind of the whole point of allowing nested divs.

Comment: I think its not possible with pure css its possible in javascript............

Comment: @ShailenderArora..can u tell me how will i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about css but this may be helpful to you. You can achieve this by creating  a JQuery function with variables as height and width of the div elements (as well as positioning). Keep those variables in relation so that whenever the div elements are resized or changed there respective div elements will change. Thus the sub div element will act as a child div.

For example:

```
var mainHeight = $('maindiv').height();
var mainWidth = $('maindiv').width();
var subHeight = $('subdiv').height();
var subWidth  = $('subdiv').width();

/*and then implement your own function*/
```

Comment: wow ! thanks that i'll be usefull. I'll try that and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/mastering-the-960-grid-system/) link and see the push and pull classes These classes may give you the idea. You need to do something like  `left: -40px;`  etc. As I know it is usually done for SEO purpose

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bXaXS/24/.
It is not a perfect solution as you wanted but it does change the height and width of `#main div` on changing the height and width of `#sub div`